# completablefutureにおいてthencomposeのメソッドチェーンを途中で抜ける方法があるか知りたい

Tags: java, java8

現在Java8のcompletablefutureを勉強しています。

表題にある通りなのですが、
**completablefutureにおいてthencomposeのメソッドチェーンを途中で抜ける方法はありますでしょうか？**

例えば以下のようなコードにおいて以下のような方法はありますでしょうか？
後者に関しては意図的にExceptionを投げる方法だけでしょうか？
Exceptionを投げるにしても意図的に投げるとしたらどのようなExceptionを投げるべきでしょうか？
・①のthenComposeで処理を終える方法
・①のthenComposeから②のexceptionallyに飛ぶ方法

```
public class CompletableFutureTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("aaaaa");
    future = future.thenCompose(s -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("bbb"))
            .thenCompose(f -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ccc"))  //①
            .thenCompose(f -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(1111))
            .thenCompose(f -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ffff"))
            .thenApply(s -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ffff"))
            .thenCompose(f -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ffff"))
            .exceptionally(s -> "ffff");  //②

    System.out.println(future.get());
}
}
```

もしわかる方がいればお願い致します。

Comment: https://www.codeflow.site/ja/article/java-completablefutureは参考になりませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！このサイトは見ましたが、解決には至りませんでした

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    boolean isThrowException = true;
    CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("aaaaa");
    future = future.thenCompose(s -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("bbb"))
            .thenCompose(f -> {
                if(isThrowException) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Its a Exception");
                }
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ccc");
            })  //①
            .thenCompose(f -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(1111))
            .thenCompose(f -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ffff"))
            .thenApply(s -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ffff"))
            .thenCompose(f -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ffff"))
            .exceptionally(s -> s.getMessage());  //②

    System.out.println(future.get());
```

これはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます